# Creating Text with different fonts using opengles 2

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, freetype

My project should display graphic overlay on the monitor using opengles2 in linux environment.

Need to display a text in different fonts on the monitor using opengles2. Freetype library can be used for rendering text in different fonts,

But I am not able to find an example program that would use freetype library in opengles2 Linux to render a text in different fonts.

Comment: One basic question, are you going to show the Text in 3D extruded mesh or just flat? You can use FTGLes for this. https://github.com/cdave1/ftgles

Comment: Need to show the Text just flat.

Comment: In that case you can use the example FTGLES

Comment: Can FTGLES be used for linux? I need a package that can be compatable (support) with OGLES2.0

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use plain freetype on anything nowadays. It is missing so many opentype/unicode smarts which have been moved to other libraries a long time ago. So it will work on simple latin text, and hit problems on pretty much anything else (including not simple latin text).

You'd properly be better of long term taking a higher-level lib that abstracts all the text bits (freetype, fontconfig, harfbuzz, freebid, etc), such as pango cairo, and plug it on opengl es.

Some links:
https://dthompson.us/font-rendering-in-opengl-with-pango-and-cairo.html
http://emblemparade.net/blog/using-cairo-with-opengl-es/
http://cairographics.org/OpenGL/